# how do I change the order of treenodes

Tags: c#

I would like to change the order of System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodes on the same level.

any suggestions on how this might be done in .net-2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void MoveNodeUp(TreeNode node)
{
  TreeNode parentNode = node.Parent;
  int originalIndex = node.Index;
  if (node.Index == 0) return;
  TreeNode ClonedNode = (TreeNode)node.Clone();
  node.Remove();
  parentNode.Nodes.Insert(originalIndex - 1, ClonedNode);
  parentNode.TreeView.SelectedNode = ClonedNode;
  }
```

Comment: why are you cloning the node? Remove should not dispose of it so the reference will still be valid.

Comment: @JMcCarty - Fixed it

Answer (score 7):

You need to manipulate the TreeView's Nodes collection. See [TreeNodeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.aspx).

If you have three tree nodes and you want to move the last one to the front, for example: (Note: not tested code, but shows the idea)

```
var lastNode = MyTreeView.Nodes[2];
MyTreeView.Nodes.Remove(lastNode);
MyTreeView.Nodes.Insert(0, lastNode);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's what I've written:

```
    public void MoveNode(TreeView tv, TreeNode node, bool up)
    {

        if ((node.PrevNode == null) && up) {
            return;
        }

        if ((node.NextNode == null) && !up) {
            return; 
        }

        int newIndex = up ? node.Index - 1 : node.Index + 1;

        var nodes = tv.Nodes; 
        if (node.Parent != null) {
            nodes = node.Parent.Nodes;
        }

        nodes.Remove(node);
        nodes.Insert(newIndex, node); 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code which does not require any cloning.

For my case it moves up one position in the sibling nodes but can be adapted

```
        TreeNode selectedNode = treeViewChain.SelectedNode;
        if (selectedNode != null && selectedNode.Index > 0)
        {
            TreeNode parent = selectedNode.Parent;
            int selectedIndex = selectedNode.Index;
            selectedNode.Remove();
            parent.Nodes.Insert(selectedIndex - 1, selectedNode);
            treeViewChain.SelectedNode = selectedNode;
        }
```